# How to efficiently recolor large images in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, image

My goal is to transform each non-null pixel, i.e. where the RGB color of the pixel is not [0, 0, 0], of an image to a certain color with alpha channel (RGBA).

My code is as below:

```js
function processMask(mask: HTMLImageElement): ImageData {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = mask.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = mask.naturalHeight;

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(mask, 0, 0);

  const color = [80, 80, 80];
  const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, mask.naturalWidth, mask.naturalHeight)
    .data
    .reduce(
      (acc, value, index) => {
        const isAlpha = index % 4 === 3;
        if ( value === 0 ) {
          acc.data[index] = value;
          // The assumption is that all channel values are set for objects
          acc.isObject = false;
        } else {
          if ( isAlpha ) {
            acc.data[index] = acc.isObject ? 100 : 0;
            acc.isObject = false;
          } else {
            acc.data[index] = color[(index % 4) % 3];
            acc.isObject = true;
          }
        }
        return acc;
      },
      { data: new Uint8ClampedArray(mask.naturalWidth * mask.naturalHeight * 4), isObject: false }
    ).data;
  return new ImageData(data, mask.naturalWidth, mask.naturalHeight);
```

My problem is as you may expect that it is really slow on large images (~2 MB) and blocks the main thread. It seems that `getImageData` and the reducer runs about the same time, taking roughly 90 % of all the time (measured with `console.time` timers). Is there a faster way to get the image data form an Image object? Is there a better way to transform the data?